# How do I group results based on information found (or not found) in another table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry if this is a simple question, I haven't had much luck with the search terms I've been using...

In my rails 3 project I have the models Project, User and UserProjectRole.

a User has many Projects, as well as a role for each project that is defined in UserProjectRole (which contains a user_id, project_id, and role).

There are 2 roles: editor and lead.

If I want to group the list of projects so current_user sees the projects they lead listed first, the projects they can edit listed second, and the projects for which they have no role listed last, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the relations (has_many, has_and_belongs_to_many, etc) between the three models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select project, decode(sort, 1, 'LEAD', 2, 'EDITOR', 'Not Assigned') role
from (
select project, role, case when user_id = <current_user_id> and role = 'LEAD' then 1
                           when user_id = <current_user_id> and role = 'EDITOR' then 2
                           else 3 end sort
from UserProjectRole
) order by sort, project;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pass the "order" option to the find?

```
User.projects.find(:all, :order => 'role_id')
```

Or if you wanted to get more specific with how you display them you can break it up into 3 separate finds for each type

```
User.projects.find(:all, :conditions { :role_id => 0 })

User.projects.find(:all, :conditions { :role_id => 1 })

User.projects.find(:all, :conditions { :role_id => 2 })
```